# stacktrace of a bound function

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, callstack, ecmascript-5

What happens to the stacktrace when you call [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on a javascript function?

For example, when I have

```
Function.prototype.arg = function() {
    var fn = this;
    return function augmented(){
        // do something with the arguments
        fn.apply(c, args); // and call it
    };
}
```

and use it on a function

```
(function x(){console.trace();}).arg()()
```

it will log

```
x
augmented
<global context>
```

So what does bind() do (internally)? It also does that partial-application and set-context things like arg() does, as you can see in the various shims (eg. [MDC's compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) function).

I know from the ecmascript specs that it will create a new function, and set internal properties of that to store the context and arguments, but it still is only a pointer to the original function (you can see that with a prototype). Yet,

```
(function x(){console.trace();}).bind()()
```

will only log

```
x
<global context>
```

Is there really no extra call inside, or is it only hidden from the trace-method?

Comment: If you use built-in `bind`, then there may be no extra call. Moreover, with inlining optimizations there still may be no extra call.

Comment: Yes, I want to know happens when the built-in bind() was used

Comment: Depends on implementation. In Chrome, for example, I can see bound function represented as `(anonymous function)` in tracer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the JS callstack always have at least one frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529328/does-the-js-callstack-always-have-at-least-one-frame)

Comment: @PaulSweatte: No, really not. Btw, I've answered that other question :-)