# Does the JS callstack always have at least one frame?

Tags: javascript, callstack, event-loop

I've recently seen a [presentation on the JS event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) which is, frankly, brilliant, but I have a lingering question now about the JS call stack. If you think about the global execution context as, say, main(), is main() never resolved? My reasoning here is that, if it were, then the JS program would be complete, and no callbacks would happen.

--edit

My primary interest here is how the call stack is represented, in relation to the callback queue. If the event loop is said to wait until the call stack is empty before pushing new frames onto the stack, then the loop would be waiting until the program is complete, and callbacks wouldn't have any effect.

I suppose that means that the event loop waits until there is *only one frame left* (the main execution context), not no frames.

Comment: Is that presentation available somewhere else, with only the slides? I've found the [transscript](http://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html), but to answer your question I'd need to see the slides. Or maybe you can link to the relevant part of the presentation?

Comment: He begins talking about the call stack right around the 10 minute mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, main() is the global execution context. It's still alive until :

- you close the tab if you're in a browser
- you kill the process if you're on a server (like node)
- the tab/process crashes

So unless one of the use cases above happen, the runtime is still alive, so is the event loop (which will process the task queue).

Comment: Thanks! So, I suppose that means the callback queue waits to push a new frame to the call stack until there is only that one main() frame left.

Comment: In fact, this is the event loop which is in charge of pushing remaining callbacks in the task queue to the main()
If main() died, the callback will end up nowhere - unless the browser (or server, or whatever environment you're in) canceled the existing timers related to the process when it died (this I don't know exactly)

Answer (score 3):

> If you think about the global execution context as, say, main()

No. `main` is not the [global execution context](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3), it is the code that initially runs in that context. The global environment is - through closure - still preserved for the outstanding callbacks after your global code ran, it will not get garbage-collected until your program has finished.

> is main() never resolved?

Of course it is. `main()` is the [invocation of any global code](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.1) - basically, when you loaded a script in your webpage and it executes (yes, this can happen multiple times). Or the global program that you tell node to execute. And once that code has finished running, it does indeed get popped of the stack, as you can see in the talks's animation very well. It does not "continue to run", as that would block the event loop.

> My reasoning here is that, if it were, then the JS program would be complete, and no callbacks would happen.

No. The script might have been completed, yes, but your program (browser environment, node etc) has not yet. The event loop is still spinning (or, to be exact: just starts spinning).

The event loop will look at the ongoing asynchronous tasks (XHRs, timeouts, file IO etc) and notice there still are some things working. The program does not exit. Once one (or multiple) of those tasks finish, they put their callback in the callback queue, where it gets picked up by the event loop, and processed by executing it on a brand new call stack. When that stack is empty again, the event loop is back in control, and picks up callbacks from the queue until it is empty. Then again, it looks whether there are still ongoing tasks (one of the callbacks might have spawned new ones), and only when there are none, then the program really ends, and the global environment can be trashed.

So yes, there are indeed times in the execution of a javascript program where the callstack is empty, and only the event loop is spinning happily - actually, that's the situation most of the time.