# Optimization of tail calls in built-in functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

You probably know what a tail call is. And you probably know that in browsers there is no support for calling tail optimization other than Safari.
According to the specification, tail optimization should be applied only in strict mode; in normal mode, it is not applied due to the fact that we can use the properties of the function of the previous call: `arguments` and `caller`.
When the implementation decides to apply tail call optimization, it calls the `PrepareForTailCall` abstract operation. As I understand it, it removes the execution context of the current function from the stack and never returns to it again. So, the specification defines 3 functions: `Function.prototype.call`, `Function.prototype.apply`, `Reflect.apply`. Each of them calls `PrepareForTailCall` without checking whether the function has a tail call or not (when I say this, I mean the built-in function from the specification (**one of**): `Function.prototype.call`, `Function.prototype.apply`, `Reflect.apply`).

*First question:* Do browsers implement a call to an operation such as PrepareForTailCall in these built-in functions?

*Second question:* If browsers implement a call to an operation such as `PrepareForTailCall` for built-in functions, can we assume that there is partial support for tail calls?

*Third question:* section [9.3](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-built-in-function-objects) says that all built-in functions are strict. What does strict functions mean (functions in which the code works in strict mode)?

---

I tried to track a function that called another function this way:

```
function output(){console.log(output.caller)} 

(function callerO(){output()})(); /// ƒ callerO(){output()}
output.call(); /// null
output.apply(); /// null
Reflect.apply(output,undefined,[]) /// null
```

For me, it looks like browsers implement tail call optimization for the 3 functions listed above. Since we can not find out who called them before.

P.S Interesting enough question for me, I would like to see your comments and answers.

Comment: Last I checked the V8 team had abandoned their TCO implementation. IIRC, it was behind a flag for Node and later completely removed. There was some sort of technical problem with it and maybe even some disagreements over TCO. I can't remember the specifics. I'm also not sure if the TCO implementation was restored at a later point.

Comment: Your example makes no sense. If you call `output()` from the global scope, you get `null` as well, for comparison you'd need to do `(function callerCall(){ output.call(); })()`.

Comment: @Bergi Why doesn't that make sense? 3 of the above functions are in fact functions that contain a call to another function. Therefore, this should not play a role where I make a call through them. In addition, I did an example as you wrote and the result is null.

Comment: @Bergi I just want to find out if stack optimization happens when we call our functions through these built-in ones. And your example, on the contrary, imposes another level of context. As a result, we have three functions, each of which must have its own context.

Comment: @Bergi you say that my examples do not make sense. Why so? For example, `Function.prototype.call` is the same function as any function that calls another function through itself. I expected from my examples something like `output.call (); /// ƒ call () {[native code]}`

Comment: @Bergi for example like this: `Function.prototype.callMine = function callMine(){this()}; output.callMine(); /// ƒ callMine(){this()}`

Comment: @MaximPro I thought you wanted to prove that `call`/`apply`/`apply` use TCO and would have the same result as a plain call to `output()`? Then one should have the `callerO` wrapper in either all examples or none.

Comment: @MaximPro It would need to be `function callMine() { "use strict"; return this(); }` to be eligible for TCO and have the same strict-mode behaviour as `call`.

Comment: Btw, I think this question is pretty similar to [stacktrace of a bound function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10166827/1048572) which I've asked years ago and still haven't found a definitive answer (other than "it probably is implementation-dependent").

Comment: @Bergi yes it is true I just wanted to show that `call / apply / apply` use TCO. Hmm, why use `callerO` in all cases? Using `callerO`, I showed that any function from which `output` is called, we see the caller property other than `null`. For the built-in, I did not do the wrapper just because it is already a function, and if you look at the specification, you can see how they make a call for the specified function.

Comment: @Bergi Yes it is correctly noticed that it is necessary to use `"use strict"`. And in that case it will be `null`. This behavior is not described in the specification in any way - can you explain it somehow?

As we know, TCO does not work in cyclic calls or in general in TC. Incomprehensible situation.

By the way, `return this ();` or  `this ();` will not necessarily, print `null` anyway.